# get first string between slashes after url

Tags: javascript

I have the following link

```
http://bulk-ccc.aaaa.com/tracking/food?
```

I need to get the first string after the url which in this case is

```
tracking
```

and also the second string

```
food
```

how this can be done with JS?

Comment: Is the URL your current location, or just a string?

Comment: use split function only

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**URL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface to parse a URL string. You can try this:

```js
const str = "http://bulk-ccc.aaaa.com/tracking/food?";
const url = new URL(str);

let parts = url.pathname ? url.pathname.split('/').filter(v => !!v) : [];

console.log(parts);
```

From this `parts` array you can get your require parts.

Comment: not good because I can get url like that as well https://google.com/?i=mainand then I don't know

Comment: Arrange your question properly then. Update the question and add what is your url would be.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string to get it into an array and then get the needed amount of elements

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').filter((x, i) => x && i < 3)
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)